# After apply seaborn yticklabels color, it is not aligned

Tags: colors, alignment, seaborn

Below graph is aligned until applying yticklabels color to white
I don't know why it is changed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0RMt.png)

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn

sns.set(rc={'axes.facecolor' : 'darkslategrey', 'figure.facecolor' : 'darkslategray', 'grid.color' : 'k', 'axes.edgecolor' : 'black',
           })

g = sns.catplot(data=desert_data,x='total_time',y='name', kind='bar', color='yellow', saturation=.7, height=3.5, aspect=2)

g.set_xticklabels(color='white')
g.set_yticklabels(color='white')
g.set_xlabels('')
g.set_ylabels('')

g.tight_layout()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cL4U.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found old matplotlib has these graph cut-off issues

Solved by installing latest matplotlib version
(3.1.1 -> 3.3.3)